# Unable to find controller in spring web mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url-routing

It seems that dispatcher-servlet unable to perform component scan using.

```
 <context:component-scan  base-package="abc" />
```

In my controller file (**HelloController.java**) under package **abc**. Code is written as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
    return "hello"; //I have already made hello.jsp in web-inf/jsp/
 }
}
```

My Application name is **SpringMiddle**. When try url as:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMiddle/hello.htm
```

I do have following url pattern in web.xml

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It shows me error HTTP 404 not found.

**EDIT:** : it shows me warning

```
WARNING:   No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMiddle/hello.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Comment: Two questions : Is your application properly deployed on server? What error did you see in stacktrace?

Comment: try to put a debug, inside the controller and check if it is working. Also post your application context file and the web.xml so people may help you.

Comment: Do you have the following in your mvc config? `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

Comment: @Taylor: no i don't have such tag there.

Comment: Try putting that in then. :)

Comment: @Taylor: Thanks for ur suggestion, but i have no idea about that tag , so far i was referring one tutorial , and going exactly what they mentioned. So i have no idea at which place i have to put that tag

Comment: also, don't put .htm on your url

Comment: @Taylor: its working now. can you tell me what was difference in tutorial i was reading on http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/  and the method suggested by you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to enable MVC in Spring. In xml config you can do it in such way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

and in JavaConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig {

}
```

Please refer to [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable)

Comment: any other alternative then this? I can't figure out that in tutorial i am referring they have not include such tag there.

Comment: No - you always have to tell Spring that you want to use MVC framework. Of course you can use Spring Boot project that enables it automatically but I think it's not your case.

Comment: Thank you very much. Done.. actually i referring this site http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

Comment: @Ritesh if you're just starting new project please consider using JavaConfig instead of xml. Or maybe even use SpringBoot - you can find nice tutorial here - https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Answer (score 3):

if you are referring to an mkyong tutorial, I didn't use the annotations: @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc, problem is you are using both annotations and xml declaration.

Annotation for setting the url:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
```

you should remove this part:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and you'll be able to visit the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMiddle/hello
```

Also make sure you have this in your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value> 
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
</listener>
```

the dispatcher-servlet.xml is where the component scanning is declared